# How to press a button, after jQuery calendar closes on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to press a button(Space) when the datepicker closes, after someone selects a date?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true     //Add auto close as true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one option in datepicker `'hide'`

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker("hide");
});
```